# Reduce Vector Point Frequency in QGIS 2.18.3

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a vector point file with 50,000+ points from a model output. I have downloaded the vector field renderer [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorFieldRenderer/) resulting in a flow direction for each point. What I would like to ultimately do is have an even distribution of arrows and have more or less arrows appear when zooming in or out. I have not yet found a way to set scale ranges to the vector arrows because as a result of the plugin, it is it's own style and I do not have the ability to set a scale range.

The other thing I am having trouble with is creating an evenly spaced array of points to significantly reduce the frequency, and then apply the vector arrow style from the plugin as a work around. Is there a way to create an even point array from a rule based style setting?

Here is my problem:[image: Too many vectors]

Comment: Try with rule based styling, set field for criteria, or set ground measure of arrows not pixel or mm.